# Retrieve last record with 2 same results SQL

Tags: sql, get, record

I have a little problem...I need to retrieve the last records for this:

> id: 0
> username: Admin
> type:logic
> id_quest:1
> risp:X
>   
> id: 1
> username: Admin
> type:logic
> id_quest:1
> risp:X
>   
> id: 2
> username: Admin
> type:logic
> id_quest:1
> risp:Y
>   
> id: 3
> username: Lol
> type:logic
> id_quest:2
> risp:Z
>   
> id: 4
> username: Lol
> type:biology
> id_quest:1
> risp:K
>   
> id: 5
> username: Lol
> type:biology
> id_quest:1
> risp:Q

I want to retrieve last record when "type and id_quest are the same", so in this case it should give: id:5, id:3 and id:2.

This is my db:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `question` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `id_quest` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `risp` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `non_contata` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=127 ;

INSERT INTO `question` (`id`, `username`, `type`, `id_quest`, `risp`, `non_contata`) VALUES
(91, 'Admin', 'biologia', 1, X, 0),
(92, 'Admin', 'biologia', 2, X, 0),
(93, 'Admin', 'logica', 3, X, 0),
(94, 'Admin', 'logica', 4, X, 0),
(73, 'J.J.J', 'biologia', 1, X, 0),
(74, 'J.J.J', 'biologia', 2, X, 0),
(75, 'J.J.J', 'biologia', 3, X, 0),
(76, 'J.J.J', 'biologia', 4, X, 0),
(109, 'Admin', 'biologia', 1, X, 0),
(110, 'Admin', 'biologia', 2, X, 0),
(111, 'Admin', 'biologia', 3, X, 0),
(112, 'Admin', 'biologia', 4, X, 0),
```

I want that query return this id: 112,111,110,109,76,75,74,73,94,93

Comment: Just thinking out lout, could you use `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I have to take more than one result for username, but there souldn't be any with same username same type and same id_quest

Answer (score 2):

By last record, you probably mean the one with the largest id.

The following should do this:

```
select *
from t
where t.id in (select max(id)
               from t
               group by type, id_quest
               having count(*) > 1
              )
```

Comment: It works but query select just username "Lol" not admin, why?

Comment: When I run it on your sample data, it returns multiple rows.  Are you sure you have the "group by" in the subquery?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it should work using grouping:

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM table
GROUP BY type, id_quest
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Assuming that by "last record" you mean the largest id and that it doesn't matter where in the table the duplicate entries are positioned.

On MySQL this query returns:

```
mysql> SELECT max(ID) FROM test GROUP BY type, id_quest ORDER BY 1 DESC;
+---------+
| max(ID) |
+---------+
|       5 |
|       3 |
|       2 |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want to compare only the immediate predecessors, then things get a bit more complicated and you need to use subqueries.

```
SELECT id
FROM question q1
WHERE
IFNULL((SELECT q2.type=q1.type FROM question q2 WHERE q2.id > q1.id ORDER BY q2.id LIMIT 1),0) = 0
OR
IFNULL((SELECT q3.id_quest=q1.id_quest FROM question q3 WHERE q3.id > q1.id ORDER BY q3.id LIMIT 1),0) = 0
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

This query compares the id_quest and type column with that of the one with the next highest id and outputs 1 if it is the same and 0 otherwise.

However, on a large table this probably will be very inefficient and it would be better to write a script that sequentially walks through each row and filters out the duplicates.

Comment: does the `ORDER BY 1 DESC` work? I always thought I had to use an alias

Comment: Yes, you can also specify the column number, although this usually  is considered as bad practice. I only use it if I select exactly one column. And as I am mostly using MySQL I am not sure if every DBS supports it.

Comment: I just tested the query. If all lines should be retrieved and only those where `type` and `id_quest` should be returned as one line you simply have to remove the `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` edit: changed it in the answer and added the output of mysql for this query.

Comment: I tried and doesn't work for me, it just retrieve me last username with same type and id_quest, not all username are shown

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. By using this query no usernames will be shown but only ids. What database system are you using?

Comment: Look my table, I mean that if there was an other username with 5/3/2 id (in your case), query wouldn't return that

Comment: I'm sorry but then I don't understand your question. Please add some more examples or a clearer explanation what exactly you want to query. I created a table with the exact same fields and the exact same data you gave in your original question and it returns what you gave as sample output.

Comment: I added more info in the question

Comment: Now I think i understand what you mean. I added another query that only filters out those duplicates that follow in the immediate row. I am not sure however, why in your second example the id 91 is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (in case id is unique or primary key):

```
Select * from tableName where id in (Select Max(id) from tableName Group By type, id_quest)
```